# nlargest on groupby with multiindex and multiple agg column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Stuggling to apply .nlargest() to my groupedby data in order to only show the largest 10 by gross revenue per index[0]

Groupedby data looks like this:

[image: Data currently]

when I run:

```
grp_data.n_largest(10,'GrossRevenue_GBP')
```

doesn't seem to be working for me, full code snippet is below:

```
tmean = lambda x :stats.trim_mean(x, 0.1)

data = data.loc[(data['YYYY'] == 2016)&(data['New_category_ID'] != 0)]

grp_data = data.groupby(['New_category','CDI_CUS_NM'])['GrossRevenue_GBP',
'OrderCount',
'% Rev', 
'MOVC_GBP', 
'Average order size']
.aggregate({'GrossRevenue_GBP':np.sum, 'OrderCount':np.sum,'% Rev': np.sum,'MOVC_GBP': tmean ,'Average order size': tmean })
.nlargest(10,'GrossRevenue_GBP')


grp_data['Country'] = 'EU'


key1 = grp_data.index.labels[0]
key2 = grp_data['GrossRevenue_GBP'].rank(ascending=False)
sorter = np.lexsort((key2, key1))

grp_data = grp_data.take(sorter)


grp_data = grp_data[['% Rev','GrossRevenue_GBP', 'MOVC_GBP','Average order size','OrderCount','Country']]
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `groupby` first Multiindex level and apply function with `nlargest`:

```
grp_data = data.groupby(['New_category','CDI_CUS_NM']) 
               .aggregate({'GrossRevenue_GBP':np.sum, 
                           'OrderCount':np.sum,
                           '% Rev': np.sum,
                           'MOVC_GBP': tmean ,
                           'Average order size': tmean })

df = grp_data.groupby('New_category')
             .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1,'GrossRevenue_GBP'))
             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```